# Identifying unknown biting insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology, ant

Pattaya (Thailand). Unknown insect (similar to a beetle) that bite: long 2 mm, large 1 mm. It has 2 front claws. Pictures[image] attached.

[image]

[image]

Probably it lost some legs when killed (I felt the bite and I instinctively crushed it).

Comment: That looks like the head of an ant. Without better photographs and the rest of the body, it will likely be unidentifiable.

Comment: Hello, it is not the head, is the whole body. I will look for a better camera to take a proper picture and post it here.

Comment: @acvill you right, I took a proper picture... 90% is just the head of an ant!